# Distribute function - Limiting Possibilities

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a very large list of lists of which I am applying the Distribute function to. Because of this, there are more than 10^9 combinations and my computer cannot handle that.

I was wondering if it was possible to limit the distribute function to give a random sample of say 100,000 of the combinations?

The code that I am using is:

```
Distribute[list1,List]
```

where list1 contains several lists.

Thanks.

Comment: maybe `k=100; Distribute[RandomSample[#,k]&/@list1,List]` or `Tuples[RandomSample[#, k]&/@list1]`?